# Python analyze method calls from other classes/modules

Tags: python, methods, code-analysis

I've got a Codebase of around 5,3k LOC with around 30 different classe. The code is already very well formatted and I want to improve it further by prefixing methods that are only called in the module that were defined in with a "_", in order to indicate that. Yes it would have been a good idea to do that from the beginning on but now it's too late :D

Basically I'm searching for a tool that will tell me if a method is not called outside of the module it was defined in, I'm not looking for stuff that will automatically convert the whole thing to use underscores, just a "simple" thing that tells me where I have to look for prefixing stuff.

I'd took a look at the AST module, but there's no easy way to get a list of method definitions and calls, also parsing the plain text yields just too many false positives. I don't insist in spending day(s) on reinventing the wheel when there might be an already existing solution to my problem.

Comment: Who would be helped by this?  Is all that work really going to help someone?

Comment: Well it would help me I guess, since I'm starting to loose the overview about where which method gets called, especially since I dont't use an IDE like PyCharm or PyDev. PyCharm has really ugly font smoothing and in Eclipse struggels a lot with the color configuration. I just can't stand black text on white background. PS: I'm the only one developing the thing: http://github.com/BonsaiDen/Atarashii/tree/next I've got a lot of free time at the moment(no job...) therefore I'm spending 75% or more of my time on this thing.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this sounds like special case of coverage.

Thus I'd take a look at coverage.py or figleaf and modify it to ignore inter-module calls.

Comment: Digging in other peoples code is even harder than writing something from scratch by my self I think, but anyways I didn't know of coverage/figleaf before so thanks for that, since it already found a bit of dead code :)